# NetLogo: how to create-links-to an extended Moore Neighbourhood

Tags: netlogo

The following code works fine for creating links to a moore neighborhood:

```
to setup
clear-all
  ask patches [
    sprout 1
  ]
  ask turtles [
    set size 0.5
  ]
end


to go 
  ask patch 0 0 [
   let investor turtles-here
       let neighborhood patch-set neighbors
       ask neighborhood [
        let turtles-in-neighborhood turtles-here
       ask investor [
        create-links-to turtles-in-neighborhood
      ]
      ]
     ]
end
```

However, when I try the coding in a similar way (see below) to create links to a double/extended Moore neighborhood, I get a runtime error message saying "A turtle cannot link to itself. error while turtle 24 running CREATE-LINKS-TO" and the error highlights the line of code "create-links-to turtles-in-neighborhood2"

```
  to go
  ask patch 0 0 [
    let investor turtles-here
        let neighborhood2 patch-set [neighbors] of neighbors
        ask neighborhood2 [
          let turtles-in-neighborhood2 turtles-here
          ask investor [
            create-links-to turtles-in-neighborhood2
     ]
     ]
    ]
end
```

Any suggestions hugely appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, this was my question, I should have kept going. I have been battling this one for a few hours but the answer was simply to create-links-to "OTHER" turtles-in-neighborhood2